# How can I go about extracting file Properties/ Metadata/ Annotations from a file

Tags: c++, qt, file, properties

**Windows: R.click -> Properties -> Details**

**.mp3:**

> Description
>   **Media**
>
> > *Contributing artists    : Dire Straits*
> >     *Album                   : 100 Greatest Guitar Solos*
> >     *Length                  : 00:05:46*
>
> Description
>   Media
>   Audio
>   Origin
>   Content
>   File

**.jpg:**

> Description
>   Origin
>   **Image**
>
> > *Image ID*
> >     *Dimensions              : 850 - 1185*
> >     *Width                   : 850 pixels*
> >     *etc*
> >     *etc*
>
> Camera
>   Advanced photo
>   File

1. How can I go about extracting file properties from a file in C++, Qt?
2. Is it possible to edit the above metadata?
3. Is it possible to add custom metadata/ Properies to a file programatically?

Answer (score 1):

there are some articles I found about extracting the metadata from an image. Hope they be useful :

https://exposingtheinvisible.org/resources/obtaining-evidence/image-digging

http://www.digitalcitizen.life/what-file-s-metadata-and-how-edit-it